# Laravel - Undefined variable: data

Tags: php, laravel-4

Trying to send an activation email with this code:

```
    $data = array(
        'activation_email'     => $user->activation_code
    );

    Mail::send('emails.auth.activate', $data, function($message) use ($user)
    {
        $message->from('test@test.com', 'Test');

        $message->to($user->email);
    });
```

And the view contains:

```
{{ $data['activation_code'] }}
```

But I'm getting the above error - what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument for `send()` takes an array containing variable names and their values.

```
$data = array(
    'activation_email'     => $user->activation_code
);
```

Will make the activation code available as variable `$activation_email`. So you can do it this way:

```
{{ $activation_email }}
```

---

If you'd prefer `$data` you could do this:

```
Mail::send('emails.auth.activate', ['data' => $data], function($message) use ($user)
```